# How to get all keys of collection that contains certain(String) value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a collection i.e. A.

I want to get all the keys to this collection that have particular value i.e. "hello"

```
   {
      "a": "its me hello",
      "b": "it does not have value",
      "c": "It has hello"
   }
```

In that case, I want to query to return **a and c** keys. Which contains the string "hello".

Is there any way to do that?

Or any way to do that in spring boot?

Comment: are field name and number of field in each object is fixed?

Comment: It can be both. Sometimes fixed. Sometimes it can't be fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by reshaping the data in the datasource using `objectToArray`

[Play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PV5NYUvfZLm)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "data.v": {
        $regex: "hello"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Another advanced version [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/plRAvfME_4v)
It reshapes the data back

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "data.v": {
        $regex: "hello"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {//Grouping back and restructuring the data so that objectToArray will bring the original format easily.
      "_id": "$_id",
      data: {
        "$addToSet": {
          k: "$data.k",
          v: "$data.v"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Refere the documentation of `arrayToObject` and `objectToArray`, then `$regex`

Comment: If you can help me. how I can use it in spring boot. It will be very helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not that expert in boot. If you try and post a question with spring-boot, anyone can help here.