# How to get all keys of collection that contains certain(String) value in mongodb using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

Suppose I have a collection i.e. A.

I want to get all the keys to this collection that have particular value i.e. "hello"

```
   {
      "a": "its me hello",
      "b": "it does not have value",
      "c": "It has hello"
   }
```

In that case, I want to query to return **a and c** keys. Which contains the string "hello".

Any way to do that in spring boot?

I got an answer to this for the mongo shell.
[Link to the answer that works in mongo shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65718367/how-to-get-all-keys-of-collection-that-contains-certainstring-value-in-mongodb).

But unable to convert it in spring-boot using MongoRepository.

I am trying the following code -

```
try {
            MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(connectionRequest.getUri());
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
            for (String databaseName : mongoClient.listDatabaseNames()) {
                logger.info("***Database: ***" + databaseName);
                MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName);
                if(database.getName().equals("forum")|| database.getName().equals("kidsventure")) {
                    MongoIterable<String> collections = database.listCollectionNames();
                    for (String collectionName : collections) {
                        logger.info("***Collection: ***" + collectionName);
                        MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = database.getCollection(collectionName);
                        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.project(Aggregation.ROOT), Aggregation.match(Criteria.where(connectionRequest.getWord())));
                        System.out.println(aggregation);
                        Iterable<Document> fields = mongoCollection.find();
                        fields.forEach(field -> {
                            String json = field.toJson();
                            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
                            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
                                System.out.println("***key***" + entry.getKey() + "***value***" + entry.getValue().toString());
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().toString().toLowerCase().equals(connectionRequest.getWord().toLowerCase()));
                                System.out.println(entry.getValue().getAsString().toLowerCase().equals(connectionRequest.getWord().toLowerCase()));
                            }
//                            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
//                                if (entry.getValue().getAsString().equals(connectionRequest.getUri())) {
//                                    System.out.println("***key***" + entry.getKey());
//                                }
//                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("***Error connecting!***" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Does nested-for returns the result?

Comment: For now, it's returning all the keys. Instead of only keys that have the matching string.

Comment: Are you using mongo template? If you use it, you don't need this much of code, its easy to implement in few lines

Answer (score 0):

`AggregateIterable<Document> queryResult = mongoCollection.aggregate(Arrays.asList (new Document("$project", new Document("data", new Document("$objectToArray", "$$ROOT"))),new Document("$unwind", "$data"),new Document("$match", new Document("data.v",new Document("$regex", "hello")))));`

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643109/mongodb-aggregation-with-java-driver)